# Why is there negative static pressure in contour?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, turbines, cfd

I studied a paper about turbine and i seen that there is negative static pressure in contour. Why does this happen?

[image]

[Wave Energy Harvesting Turbine: Performance Enhancement](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705815019244)

Comment: If you have studied a paper, then at least post a reference to that paper.

Comment: Was it a "wake" region?

Comment: I place reference...
no it wasn't....It is near to stagnation point of blade.